# How to use Helm Jenkins Values 'CredentialsXmlSecret'

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy a Jenkins using helm. I saw that some values are set with an XML. However, I can't do it the same way with the Master.CredentialsXmlSecret field. I have tried:

```
CredentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials

SecretsFilesSecret:
jenkins-credentials: |-
xml from credentials.xml here
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the groovy init scripts, you can add in the helm values like this:

```
  InitScripts:
    01-passwords: |- 
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*;
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*;
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*;

    String keyfile = "/tmp/key"

    Credentials c = (Credentials) new UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl(CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "description", "user", "password")


    def ksm1 = new CertificateCredentialsImpl.FileOnMasterKeyStoreSource(keyfile)
    Credentials ck1 = new CertificateCredentialsImpl(CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "description", "password", ksm1)

    def ksm2 = new CertificateCredentialsImpl.UploadedKeyStoreSource(keyfile)
    Credentials ck2 = new CertificateCredentialsImpl(CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "description", "password", ksm2)

    SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().addCredentials(Domain.global(), c)
    SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().addCredentials(Domain.global(), ck1)
    SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().addCredentials(Domain.global(), ck2)
```

This script in the configuration, create the credentials and setup in your jenkins.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is start up a Jenkins instance, configure it the way I want, `exec` into it (e.g., `kubectl exec -it {my-jenkins-pod} /bin/bash`), `cd` into `/var/jenkins_home`, and just grab the appropriate files and base64 encode them.

In this case the appropriate files are:

```
/var/jenkins_home/credentials.xml
/var/jenkins_home/secrets/master.key
/var/jenkins_home/secrets/hudson.util.Secret
```

You can just `base64 -w 0 credentials.xml` for instance to get the base64 encoded contents of any of those files.  Then just copy it and paste it into the appropriate k8s secret.

The first k8s secrete you need to create is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jenkins-credentials
data:
  credentials.xml: AAAGHckcdhie==
```

Where the value given to `credentials.xml` is a `base64` encoded string of the contents of the credentials.xml file.

The other k8s secret you need to create is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jenkins-secrets-secret
data:
  master.key: AAAdjkdfjicki+
  hudson.util.Secret: AAAidjciud=
```

Then in your `values.yaml`:

```
CredentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials
SecretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets-secret
```

**Edit: Since [Apr 22, 2019](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/13136), version 1.00, the name convention has changed**

Thanks to ythdelmar, who pointed out in the comments, it is now

```
credentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials
secretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets-secret
```

without the first capital.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work. . .followed your excellent example verbatom, but when Jenkins starts up I get crypto errors saying there is a generic cryptographic error, that it needs to be divisible by 16
Tried a couple times now.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's now `credentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials`and `secretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets-secret`, without the first capital

Comment: Thanks @ythdelmar, I will try to update this answer to conform to the changes ASAP.  I haven't upgraded our Jenkins install yet because it's a pretty massive change.  Also, as far as I know, this method in general is deprecated so I may update to use the JCasC method but I'll have to use it myself first.